# Image not appearing on Jekyll site

Tags: html, jekyll

I'm working on creating a Jekyll site based on a fork of: https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now.

I am trying to replace the header with my own header image but the image shows up as a broken link.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper-masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="masthead clearfix">
     <img src="https://goo.gl/photos/pnvSq1hjp4NX9PPq5">
      <nav>
        <a href="/">Blog</a>
        <a href="/about">About</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply because [`https://goo.gl/photos/pnvSq1hjp4NX9PPq5`](https://goo.gl/photos/pnvSq1hjp4NX9PPq5) doesn't redirect to an image file.

[This](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HNy8Td1CVPcyGEyisc2DjAD0jQeF4gf8fR4ZFcM-5Z19OgFLwhujmmSd7Lw-s6CkKtWHGNJep2gGQ2P0973cB5xBpVhyw_2s1XAk2OQLVKIOFJjTky-OJ1sk9Rv_9rzHcpRBvmS7Y0BIB7a_pB34AB34oJl7NIBh9bBvMdhl36ogVCzjIfk9Tg0wS-crAOEoRfl5yvgUXwHnWeZzj_LZ0b0gFElUFvhYYvJ5LAxXLVjk_AuOcaR4WTuXOTdYHAU2311M26VVOJb7UD0nYDholpt0uioTvNDT3iqCVvMu1LijWqc9qWdyLfh5BzBOk17iSnofTnPNH9PKKRonKpRF_sf-OOagwpGu_BScMfhQns0qusCj3O2SyMbh2577a2Yj9sgNI5LTTyl3GIVMX_PnIPmGuVpe7k7gCZ3jnqwMCy-kz6xCH3XS3asiqCBGmjC4m6yziYMyzYE2xjB7C_LMf_NE7YUu96C8vIW1tbTccUlyTWLO_GKeeuWy3wCm0EceuVhJPNBSmqd4-D3wJ8A9ga2xJkfFSi2kDwxKuyMkPbDQiTrCP0Q6S6lAPpBM7Zh9nKI9=w678-h90-no) is the image URL you want to use.

```
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HNy8Td1CVPcyGEyisc2DjAD0jQeF4gf8fR4ZFcM-5Z19OgFLwhujmmSd7Lw-s6CkKtWHGNJep2gGQ2P0973cB5xBpVhyw_2s1XAk2OQLVKIOFJjTky-OJ1sk9Rv_9rzHcpRBvmS7Y0BIB7a_pB34AB34oJl7NIBh9bBvMdhl36ogVCzjIfk9Tg0wS-crAOEoRfl5yvgUXwHnWeZzj_LZ0b0gFElUFvhYYvJ5LAxXLVjk_AuOcaR4WTuXOTdYHAU2311M26VVOJb7UD0nYDholpt0uioTvNDT3iqCVvMu1LijWqc9qWdyLfh5BzBOk17iSnofTnPNH9PKKRonKpRF_sf-OOagwpGu_BScMfhQns0qusCj3O2SyMbh2577a2Yj9sgNI5LTTyl3GIVMX_PnIPmGuVpe7k7gCZ3jnqwMCy-kz6xCH3XS3asiqCBGmjC4m6yziYMyzYE2xjB7C_LMf_NE7YUu96C8vIW1tbTccUlyTWLO_GKeeuWy3wCm0EceuVhJPNBSmqd4-D3wJ8A9ga2xJkfFSi2kDwxKuyMkPbDQiTrCP0Q6S6lAPpBM7Zh9nKI9=w678-h90-no">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this actually ended up being a larger issue with the jekyll formatting, but it is resolved.